# Firebase cloud function return error Error: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I want to setCustomUserClaims in trigger function but then I get this error

[image]

This is my piece of code:

```
   exports.onCreateCompaniesByUserFunction = 

  functions.firestore.document('/companiesByUser/{userId}').onWrite((change,  context) => {
        const  { userId } = context.params;

        const document = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;

        console.log('document',document)
        let owner =  []
        let employee = []
         let editor = []

    Object.keys(document).map(key => {
      if (document[key] == 'affiliate' || document[key] == 'employee') {
        employee.push( key )
      } else if (document[key] == 'owner') {
        owner.push( key )
      } else if (document[key] == 'editor') {
        editor.push( key )
      }
    });


    console.log('owner',owner)
    console.log('employee',employee)
    console.log('editor',editor)
    console.log('before the claims 2',userId)
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId, {employee, owner, editor})
    .then(() => {

      console.log('claim set successfully!');
      return true;



    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('in error',error);
    });

});
```

According to that UserId is exist but in the logs, it is saying that There is no user corresponding.

Comment: And you've verified that there is indeed a user in the Firebase Authentication dashboard with the same id as `userId`?  Because the error message is saying that there isn't.

Comment: Yes... there is indeed, in Firebase Authentication dashboard I can find the same userID. that's why it is wired.

Comment: You could have multiple projects. You could be using the service account credentials for a different project.

Comment: yes, the configuration for functions cloud function was different, and it was pointing to different database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the correct database configuration? Maybe you forgot to change your connection from staging to production. You should double check your database configuration (Usually in `functions/index.js`):

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: YOUR_CREDENTIAL_FILE,
  databaseURL: 'YOUR_DATABSE_URL',
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Try clicking on "Authentication" on the right of the Firebase home screen. Then, click "Get Started".

Enable all of the sign-in methods you're using.

This solved the problem for me.